# "all" vs "both"

Tags: meaning, grammar, word-usage, american-english

I am wondering whether "all" and "both" mean exactly the same.

I always use "both" to refer to explicitly two things, like

> Red and orange both are my favorite colors.

As for "all", I would only use it when the number of things is more than or equal to three, like

> All China, Japan, Korea are Asian countries.

My friends told me that "both" and "all" have actually the same meaning, so could anyone give me some suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: First, be aware that your second sentence is unidiomatic, not because you used "all" instead of "both", but because you used a word before "China" at all. Delete it and the sentence will become perfectly standard and idiomatic. Second: ignore your friends (unless they are native speakers, then ask them to clarify precisely what they're saying). *All* and *both* are not equivalent. As you say, *both* is strictly used for exactly 2 items, *all* is used for any number of items greater than 1 (and sometimes any number of items at all). Looking the words up in a solid dictionary should clarify.

Comment: @DanBron thanks for that, how about " China, Japan and Korea are all Asian countries"?

Comment: Yes, that works fine. Note that you could *not* substitute "both" for "all" in that sentence, precisely because you are talking about more than 2 counties.

Comment: @DanBron Yes, I see the difference now. Thank you!

Comment: What does your dictionary say about the two words? Which do you trust more, your dictionary or your friend?

Comment: @DanBron You could say "*All of* China, Japan and Korea are Asian countries." or "*All of* China, Japan and Russia are *not* Asian countries." meaning whole countries. Maybe not the best examples, but along the lines of "All of the apples are red."

Answer (score 2):

Both is used for exactly two items while 'all' is used for referring to more than one items, collectively.

Comment: +1 because you make a valid point. However, you could improve your answer by providing a few examples to support it. That way, the answer appears a little more complete. Cheers !

Comment: Okay I will keep that in mind.

Comment: How do these sentences sound? "I have two sisters. They all live in Japan."

Answer (score 1):

According to [About Education](http://esl.about.com/od/grammarintermediate/a/cm_bothand.htm) and SAT Grammar, "both" is a set of paired conjunctions and can only be used to denote two different things in it's most basic form. It also has a specific structure due to idiomatic phrasing:

> Both __ and __
>
> ____ and ___ are both ____ (more specific to these sentences)

This means that this is incorrect:

> Red and orange both are my favorite colors.

The correct way of sentence is by following the sentence formula of "Both":

> Both red and orange are my favorite colors.
>   Red and orange are both my favorite colors

"All" is used to define more than one items in a list. It also has a specific word placement, meaning that this is incorrect:

> All China, Japan, Korea are Asian countries.

"All" should be used in a specific way in a list:

> China, Japan, and Korea are all Asian countries