# Is there a good replacement for "both" in this sentence? (Which refers to three items.)

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, word-request

This [sentence](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/79322/41775) refers to three items:

> You can bring both the smartphone, laptop and power bank charger in
>   your hand luggage.

I've seen from this [answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/83143/26160) that "all" is more correct when referring to three or more entities. However, "all" doesn't work in this sentence.

1. Is the sentence alright as it is?
2. If no, can I replace another word for "both"?
3. Or, do I have to restructure the sentence completely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I don't think so since [*both*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/both) specifically refers to two things.
2. I would consider omitting *both*.

   > You can bring <strike>both</strike> the smartphone, laptop and power bank charger in your hand luggage.

   You can replace *both* with *all of them*,  *all three*, *all three of them*, *the three*, etc., but it would require some extra punctuation.
   *Example.*

   > You can bring all three (the smartphone, laptop, and power bank charger) in your hand luggage.
3. From context, it's clear which three items we're talking about, so you can simply write, for example,

   > You can bring all three in your hand luggage.

   Lastly, you can use *both*, but it takes some restructuring.
   *Example.*

   > You can bring both the smartphone and the power bank charger, and/plus/(in addition to) the laptop in your hand luggage.

   I paired the smartphone and the power bank charger since those are the two new items.

Comment: I've utilized this advice in the answer.